# CoreData relationship with subclass

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I have the following coredata entities:

`Event, User, SpecialUser`, such that `SpecialUser` is a subclass of `User`, and there is a relationship `Event.owner` to `User`

I am running into a situation where I want to say

`event.owner = specialUser`, but this throws the error

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "owner"; desired type = User; given type = SpecialUser;`

I have also tried casting during the assignment, e.g. `event.owner = (User *) specialUser`, to no avail.

Comment: How have you setup the superclass subclass relationship between the entities? Do you have User.h/m and SpecialUser.h/m files?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `Event` entity type has an `owner` relationship that points to the `User` entity type. If that's the case, you can only ever assign a `User` to that relationship.

The fact that the `SpecialUser` **class** subclasses the `User` **class** is not relevant to Core Data. What it cares about are the **entity types**. Class inheritance is meaningless if there's no corresponding entity inheritance. Basically, your class inheritance and entity inheritance should match.

Make the `SpecialUser` entity type inherit from the `User` entity type, to parallel the class hierarchy. Then you can assign a `SpecialUser` as the owner, and it will be valid for Core Data.

Comment: The `SpecialUser` already has its Parent Entity set as `User`

Comment: Check again, because your error message says that this is not true.